# custom ConfigurationSection with sectionGroup not working

Tags: c#, .net

When trying to access `ConnectionConfiguration` always returns the default value or `0` for an integer data type. No errors are thrown, it just cannot get the value of each of the properties. Please help me solve this problem.

I have an app.config file in console application as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="templates" >
      <section name="connections" type="Test.ConnectionConfiguration, Test" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <templates>
    <connections allowed="true" port="8080">
      <internal name="local" size="1344"/>
      <external name="internet" value="http" />
    </connections>
  </templates>
</configuration>
```

The classes

```
public class ConnectionConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("allowed", IsRequired = true)]
    public bool Allowed
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["allowed"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["allowed"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("port", IsRequired = true)]
    public int Port
    {
        get { return (int)this["port"]; }
        set { this["port"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("internal")]
    public InternalElement Internal
    {
        get { return (InternalElement)this["internal"]; }
        set { this["internal"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("external")]
    public ExternalElement External
    {
        get { return (ExternalElement)this["external"]; }
        set { this["external"] = value; }
    }
}
public class InternalElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "local", IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 60)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("size", DefaultValue = "1234", IsRequired = false)]
    [IntegerValidator(ExcludeRange = false, MaxValue = 6000, MinValue = 1)]
    public int Size
    {
        get { return (int)this["size"]; }
        set { this["size"] = value; }
    }
}
public class ExternalElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "local", IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 60)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value", DefaultValue = "https", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)this["value"]; }
        set { this["value"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration();
int test = config.Port; // it should be 8080 but it's 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately just creating a new instance of the configuration handler doesn't automatically populate it with the config data. You have to read that manually. In order to achieve that you can add a static property in the ConnectionConfiguration class such as:

```
public class ConnectionConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static ConnectionConfiguration connections = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("templates/connections") as ConnectionConfiguration;
    public static ConnectionConfiguration Connections
    {
        get
        {
            return connections;
        }
    }
 // the rest is the same
}
```

and in your application you can now access the custom config section like this:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = ConnectionConfiguration.Connections;
int test = config.Port; // it should now be 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code get the section you are looking for
`ConnectionConfiguration config = (ConnectionConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("templates/connections");

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx